# How to extract molecular properties in Avogadro software

Tags: python

I'm working on a python program that can extract molecular properties from Avogadro. But the module 'Avogadro' is not working and gives an error massage ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'avogadro'. How can I over come this problem?
There is a problem because in Pypi you can see it says that pip install Avogadro will install the module. But it do not install the module.

Comment: Have you installed that package?

Comment: On the console type `pip list` and check if Avogadro is listed. If not, you have to install it